# Translation of all that is gold does not glitter

Tags: traduction, anglais

Je ne parle pas bien Français, mais Je fais un imprimé typographique de célèbre 
le Seigneur des Anneaux poème en Français. Le imprimé est pour ma copine Français, donc j'espère si quelqu peut faire un très bon traduction de suivant:

```
All that is gold does not glitter,
Not all those who wander are lost;
The old that is strong does not wither,
Deep roots are not reached by the frost.
From the ashes a fire shall be woken,
A light from the shadows shall spring;
Renewed shall be blade that was broken,
The crownless again shall be king.
```

Merci beaucoup!

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately, there's a difference between asking clarifications/help about French language issues and thinking of this website as a translation office.

Comment: @Begueradj I understand this isn't the purpose of this forum. I do speak french, but I couldn't find a copy of the French Lord of the Rings, so I asked for help. I apologize for this.

Comment: That is ok gentilhomme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my French version of the book:

> Tout ce qui est or ne brille pas,
>   Tous ceux qui errent ne sont pas perdus ;
>   Le vieux qui est fort ne dépérit point.
>   Les racines profondes ne sont pas atteintes par le gel.
>   Des cendres, un feu s'éveillera.
>   Des ombres, une lumière jaillira ;
>   Renouvelée sera l'épée qui fut brisée,
>   Le sans-couronne sera de nouveau roi.

This translation (by F. Ledoux) is pretty acurate, the only difference with your text is the full stop at the end of the 3rd and 5th verses.

Comment: Merci, Je suis reconnaissant; J'ai essayé trouver pour un livre numérique, mais que je n'aie pas essayé une exemplaire.